# Rational Root Theorem for Multivariable Polynomial with Variable Coefficients

Tags: polynomials, rational-numbers

Is it valid to use the rational root theorem on a polynomial with variable integer coefficients? Does it change anything if you have constraints making the variables interdependent?

For example, can I use the rational root theorem with:

$$
d^{6}+4dm^{9}-10dv^{6}m^{6}+15dv^{12}m^{3}-8dv^{18}+27v^{3}m^{3}
$$
to say $d$ can only take rational integer values of factors of $27v^3m^3$ when $d,v,m$ are known integers?

What if I have constraint equations such that they covary? Such as $b=\frac{v^3m^6}{d^\frac{1}2}$ where $b$ is another variable also known to be an integer, or more constraint equations.

Comment: You can fix the other variables and think of it as a polynomial in only one variable.

Comment: What do you mean by fix? It's not possible to put the equation in one variable. Oh you mean treat them as constants. Thanks thats what I thought.